# DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to execute a python script for web scraping and I have this problem that I haven't been able to solve.

Could anyone help me? Thank you

```
 DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stock_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: use
  "driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver', options=options)"
instead of
  "driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)"