# <ipython-input-10-d3f251fa1d7a>:1: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options driver = webdriver.Chrome(

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### GOAL

- Use Selenium in a JS continuously loading webpage via python web crawling task from an ec2 aws ubuntu 20.04 LTS instance

### MAIN CODE PART

```
CHROME_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

WINDOW_SIZE = '1200, 800'
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('headless') # chrome runs without a GUI window - as server doesn't have a gui  
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=%s' % WINDOW_SIZE)
#chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('hide-scrollbars')
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_PATH, 
                          options=chrome_options)
```

### That I have tried to use afterwards

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,
    chrome_options=chrome_options,
)
```

Warning message generated that is on for 1 min

```
<ipython-input-10-d3f251fa1d7a>:1: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(
```

Than after 1 min error message

```
<ipython-input-8-d3f251fa1d7a>:1: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d3f251fa1d7a> in <module>
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(
      2     executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,
      3     chrome_options=chrome_options,
      4 )  
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     74 
     75         try:
---> 76             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     77                 self,
     78                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

### Solutions I have tried

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

- [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374764/deprecationwarning-use-options-instead-of-chrome-options-driver-webdriver-chr)
- [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)
- RECOMENDATION
  CODE

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

ERORR

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
2022-07-13 12:01:46,665 INFO ====== WebDriver manager ======
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-14e7ef31432c> in <module>
      8 options.add_argument("start-maximized")
      9 
---> 10 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
     11 driver.get('https://www.google.com/' class="ansi-blue-fg">)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py in install(self)
     36 
     37     def install(self) -> str:
---> 38         driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
     39         os.chmod(driver_path, 0o755)
     40         return driver_path

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py in _get_driver_path(self, driver)
     27 
     28     def _get_driver_path(self, driver):
---> 29         binary_path = self.driver_cache.find_driver(driver)
     30         if binary_path:
     31             return binary_path

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver_cache.py in find_driver(self, driver)
     93         os_type = driver.get_os_type()
     94         driver_name = driver.get_name()
---> 95         driver_version = driver.get_version()
     96         browser_version = driver.browser_version
     97 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver.py in get_version(self)
     41     def get_version(self):
     42         self._version = (
---> 43             self.get_latest_release_version()
     44             if self._version == "latest"
     45             else self._version

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py in get_latest_release_version(self)
     35 
     36     def get_latest_release_version(self):
---> 37         self.browser_version = get_browser_version_from_os(self.chrome_type)
     38         log(f"Get LATEST {self._name} version for {self.browser_version} {self.chrome_type}")
     39         latest_release_url = (

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/utils.py in get_browser_version_from_os(browser_type)
    150         return get_browser_version(browser_type, metadata)
    151 
--> 152     cmd_mapping = {
    153         ChromeType.BRAVE: {
    154             OSType.LINUX: linux_browser_apps_to_cmd(

KeyError: 'google-chrome'
```

Answer (score 2):

chrome_options = Options() shows DeprecationWarning thats meaning is that in near future they will not use it. So use   `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` instead.

**Full example:**

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

[WebDriverManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/)